# Search box and asp-route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have just added search box to an index view

```
<form asp-action="Index" asp-route-account="@Model.First().AccountId" method="get">
            <div class="form-actions ">
                <p>
                    <input id="searchStringId" type="text" name="searchString" value="@ViewData["currentFilter"]" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-account="@Model.First().AccountId">Back to Full List</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
```

This gives me:
https://localhost:44377/MainUsers/Funds?searchString=aldi

But I need
https://localhost:44377/MainUsers/Funds?account=1&&searchString=aldi In other words I need the search string to also include the route id.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need the search string to also include the route id. Any ideas?

You can try to achieve the requirement by using a hidden input field as below.

```
<input name="account" type="hidden" value="@Model.First().AccountId" />
<input id="searchStringId" type="text" name="searchString" value="@ViewData["currentFilter"]" />
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Thats great